# How can I make a Windows Explorer file preview screen in WPF?

Tags: wpf, coding-style, preview, handlers

I'm working on an application that will have attachments, and I would like to create a type of display like in windows Explorer, where you choose a "Details" view, and also show the preview pane.

I would like to be able to show a thumbnail view of the attached file currently selected, based on the file extension.

Does anyone know where I can start to look for examples on how to pull this off?

I know Outlook 2007 can also do something similar using [preview handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144143(VS.85).aspx). I think that’s going to be the direction I want to go in, but I'm not sure where to start.

Many thanks.

[All Hail the Glory of the Hypnotoad!](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/badastronomy/2009/06/09/sweet-gorilla-of-manila-futurama-is-really-coming-back/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could do it in WPF, you [should not do it](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2006/12/18/1317290.aspx).
Seriously: **don't do it!** - you would break many apps (including one of mine).

To do this without .NET, see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellextguide9.aspx) for a nice guide.

Comment: Fair enough, but there has to be a way to pull the same type of thing off nativly.

Comment: edited my post with a link to guide on how to do this the native way.

Comment: Well if Russ wantss to host a previewer, not make one, that should not be a problem? Also MSDN article says that the previewers are hosted out of process and so may not be affected by multi-CLR problem.

Comment: Yes, all I want to do is host them. And anything outside of .NET isn't really an option, since the whole application is written in WPF where I want to use this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can start here

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/eyal/archive/2007/07/29/Hosting-vista_2F00_office-2007-previewers-in-winform-application.aspx

(the code is partially black on black, at least for me, but you can disable the styles or just copy it)